# UIAlertView is not showing. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone

Here is the code:

```
-(IBAction)signUpBtnPressed:(id)sender
{

 UIAlertView *alert = [
        [UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle:@"k"
        message:@"Thanks for Signing up!"
        delegate:nil
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue..."
        otherButtonTitles:nil
        ];
 [alert show];
 [alert release];
}
```

I also have my Sign Up button attached to this action in my view.

Comment: Do an `NSLog(@"This actually gets executed!");` in the IBAction, and check. As many others have said, this code probably never gets called, because you're doing everything right in this example.

If you can't find what the NSLog printed in the console, you might have to check your connections in the Interface Builder again :)

Answer (score 1):

I would check that all the connections are made in IB, if you're using IB to create the UI. Specifically, check whether the `UIButton` in your interface XIB that is supposed to call `signUpBtnPressed:(id)sender` has its Touch Up Inside event linked this method, and that the 'File's Owner' of the XIB is set to be the view controller that this method is in.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot release the object before it is shown!!!

Save it as an instance variable and release it later.

Answer (score 0):

Set delegate to nil.

Comment: Tried that. Still, nothing happens.

Comment: In that case, this method is never getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint where you call [alert show] to ensure that your code is called

My guess is that this method is not getting called at all. You've probably missed a connection in interface builder

Answer (score 0):

Can you print out something or try to set breakpoints. If it does not print out anything or does not stop in breakpoint. I strongly believe that the method is never get called

Answer (score 0):

Call it after a delay of 0.1 sec [self performSelector:@selector(signUpBtnPressed:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.10];

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

please set delegate to self. 
Hope this will solve your problem.